# Open Source - With Intellectual property

Tags: distribution, open-source-definition, intellectual-property

Recently I have been to open-source stuff and most of the time I license my projects under MIT License.

While open-sourcing projects, how do I "exclude" certain files and assets like "logos", "databases",etc from being open-sourced (Other words my Intellectual property) ? Like For Eg. If we have a built open source game lets say. How do I prevent game graphics, avatars, etc from being open-sourced but allow the game engine to be open source?

Note: I have read this [How to chose a open source license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898/how-do-you-choose-an-open-source-license) And also this [Open Source Definition](https://opensource.org/osd).

Comment: I've reopened your question (as you removed the part that was an overt duplicate).  But could you please read [Proprietary resources in GPLv3 project](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9839/proprietary-resources-in-gplv3-project) and let us know whether it answers your question, and if not, what remains unanswered?  Note that although that question specifically addresses GPL+proprietary, the answers apply equally to MIT+proprietary.

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks for your response, The question you mentioned talks about logos specifically, and trademarking them, Or storing them in a separate location. But in my case I need these graphics if possible to be in the same folder structure. Also what if I have a program requiring a data set to run, For eg. weather details of 2021. I Don't want  this to be given under MIT license, but the application itself which runs on this data set.  The user if he wants can upload/use a new dataset of weather details of 2023 if he wants which is owned by him.

Comment: Also I majorly use Github for Open-Sourcing, so if the response could be oriented towards its implementation in that, then it would be more helpful for me.

Comment: You might find this question and answer helpful, which deals with different parts under different licenses: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13285/how-to-license-my-game-projects-artwork-and-source-code-and-credit-others-art